# MySQL Batch Inserts - Crashing with OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, batch-processing

I am trying to insert two million rows into a MySQL table with Batch Insert. Following is the code I have.

```
   public void addItems(List<Item> Items) {
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        st = conn.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
        for (Item item : items) {
            int index = 1;
            st.setString(index++, item.getA());
            st.setString(index++, item.getB());
            st.setLong(index++, item.getC());
            st.setInt(index++, item.getD());
            st.setFloat(index++, item.getE());
            st.setInt(index++, item.getF());
            st.setString(index++, item.getG());
            st.setString(index++, item.getH());
            st.addBatch();
        }
        st.executeBatch();
        st.clearBatch();
     }
   }
```

I  call this `addItems()` function multiple times(sequentially) and I pass no more than 100 items per call. What I observe is that this `addItems()` call successfully returns and I process more and more data(in fact all the 2 million rows) by sequentially calling `addItems()`, and then finally my program crashes with an `OutOfMemoryException`, while I find that only 100 rows inserted in the table out of 2 million rows that Java has processed. I have also set `autoCommit` to true.

Other parameters that would be of interest -

MySQL

> buffer_pool_size = default value(128 MB)
> log_file_size = default value(5 MB)
>
> DB Connection String "jdbc:mysql://host:port/database?useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true";

I have already allocated 512MB to Java process.

Maximum number of connections: 10
Min connections: 1

Questions -

1. Is the preparedStatement.executeBatch() call an asynchronous
   operation or does the MySQL connector buffer these calls before
   sending it to the database?
2. How do I ensure that 100 rows are committed first and then process
   the next set of rows?
3. Will increasing buffer_pool_size and log_file_size help faster inserts?
   I do not have access to DB host, so have not tried this yet.
   I will try this when I have access.
4. How to solve this issue? - I cannot  get further because of this.

Comment: Don't use `autoCommit = true` with batch execution unless you have thoroughly verified it, the JDBC spec mentions that drivers aren't required to support it and that the behavior with `autoCommit = true` is implementation defined.

Comment: I wonder how do you know that only 100 rows entered and the problem is in the code you presenting. I have simple main app that sequentially inserts 100K rows in bulks of 100. It doesn't look like st.executeBatch() returns before statement is executed

Answer (score 0):

1.You can allways look at the code to figure stuff like this. Looking at the source code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java.html), lines 1443-1447 seems like the answer is - it depends. For example, the version, or if the batch size is larger then 3 (otherwise it's not worth the effort).

4.What I did in similar situation is executing the batch after each X rows (let's say,  100).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In fact, I am calling addItems with only 100 entries in the list. addItems function successfully returns without any exception, but I cannot find the data in DB. (I don't think it is a problem with the insert query - as this works well with smaller dataset.).

Comment: Try to call addItems with 50 entries, does it help?